# PHP: Can't access $_SESSION inside included file

Tags: php, oop, session, session-variables, superglobals

I'm working on a user authentication class in PHP and have encountered some problems with session handling.

This is the basics:

1. `global.php` I have a file called `global.php` that's included at the beginning of each pageload. From this file I also include additional classes used, for example the `class.uservalidation.php` that I'm working on.
   I initiate the session in the `global.php` file.
2. `class.uservalidation.php` When this class is instantiated in the beginning of the `global.php`file there is a call to a `checkLogin` method in the constructor that checks the session variables `email`and `hash` and if they match it will set the `auth` property to the level of the selected user.
3. `login.php` is the login page (obviously...) and when submitted this will call the `login` method of the uservalidation class. This method will set two session variables, `email` and `hash` when there's a successful login.
4. `index.php` is the default landing page that will show different content depending on the login status

And this is an example of how it works:

I go to `login.php`. Session is started, classes loaded an instantiated. `checkLogin`method will first report `auth=0`. I submit the form and the same page is loaded again. `checkLogin` will first report `auth=0` yet again as the class is instantiated. Then in the `login.php` script I will call the `login` method and the session variables are set.

BUT...

I can see the session variables when I do `print_r($_SESSION);` only from the `login.php` file and NOT from `global.php` OR `class.uservalidation.php` (even if this is where I set the session variables).

This is a problem since I need to check the `email` and `hash` session variables from the `loginCheck` method on subsequent page loads.

Since `$_SESSION` is a superglobal I thought it would be accessible from anywhere, and I can't figure out what is wrong...

I have a feeling I'm missing something very basic here... I'm quite new to OOP so it might be that I'm missing some knowledge on how to declare variables or something but since it's a superglobal I thought it wouldn't matter.

**[EDIT #1]**

And here is some code (for some reason I can't paste into this textbox so I've created links to pastebin instead):

global.php:

```
<?php
// Load configuration
require 'config.php';

// Start secure session
session_start();

// Include libraries
require 'class.uservalidation.php';

//Connect to database

// Initialize user validation
$USER=new Uservalidation();

?>
```

class.uservalidation.php

```
<?php
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class.uservalidation.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Based on example at http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

*/

class Uservalidation {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->data=FALSE;
        $this->auth=0;
        $this->loginCheck();
    }

    // login function is provided a hashed password directly from the browser (see uservalidation.js)
    public function login($email,$hash) {
        global $DB;
        if($email=filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email=$DB->real_escape_string($email);
            $hash=$DB->real_escape_string($hash);
            if($user=sql_fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' AND user_hash='$hash' AND user_status>1 LIMIT 1")) {
                // Successful login
                $user_browser=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $_SESSION['session_email']=$user['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['session_hash']=hash('sha512',$user['hash'].$user_browser);
                $this->data=$user;
                $this->auth=$user['user_auth'];
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                // Email and hash does not match
                // Record attempt in login_attempts table
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            // Not a valid email address
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->destroySession();
        $this->data=FALSE;
        $this->auth=0;
    }

    // Validate user session
    private function loginCheck() {
        $user_browser=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if($user=$this->getUser($_SESSION['session_email'])) {
            $user_hash=hash('sha512',$user['user_hash'].$user_browser);
            if(hash_equals($user_hash,$_SESSION['session_hash'])) {
                // Successful match
                $this->data=$user;
                $this->auth=$user['user_auth'];
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                // Hashes does not match
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            // User doesn't exist
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Get data for specific user (either by email, uid or hash)
    public function getUser($string) {
        global $DB;
        //echo "User: $string";
        if($email=filter_var($string,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $checkuser=sql_fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        } elseif($id=filter_var($string,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
            $checkuser=sql_fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$id' LIMIT 1");
        } else {
            $hash=$DB->real_escape_string($string);
            $checkuser=sql_fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_hash='$hash' LIMIT 1");
        }
        return $checkuser;
    }

    private function clearSession() {
        // Unset all of the session variables.
        $_SESSION=array();
    }

    private function destroySession() {
        $this->clearSession();

        // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
        // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
        if(ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params=session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
            );
        }

        // Finally, destroy the session.
        session_destroy();
    }
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';

// Process login (field "p" is created in uservalidation.js and contain the SHA512 hash of the password so raw password will never be sent to server)
if(isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['p'])) {
    if($USER->login($_POST['user_email'],$_POST['p'])) {
        //header('location:index.php');
        $html.="<pre>";
        $html.=print_r($_SESSION,TRUE);
        $html.=print_r($USER,TRUE);
        $html.="</pre>";
        $html.="<a href='index.php'>Go on!</a>";
    } else {
        $html="<p>Could not log in...</p>";
    }
} else {
    $theform=new htmlForm('login.php');
    $theform->addInput('Username',array('type' => 'email', 'name' => 'user_email', 'required' => '', 'autocomplete' => 'off'));
    $theform->addInput('Password',array('type' => 'password', 'name' => 'password', 'required' => ''));
    $theform->addInput(FALSE,array('type' => 'button', 'value' => 'Login', 'class' => 'button', 'onclick' => 'formhash(this.form);'));
    $html=$theform->render();
}

// Render Page
//=================================================================================================
?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NGI Skunkworks</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icons/foundation-icons.css" />
</head>

<body>
<?php require '_menu.php'; ?>

<div class="row">
<br>
<div class="large-12 columns">
<?php echo $html; ?>
</div>
</div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/sha512.js"></script>
<script src="js/uservalidation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Then you are starting the session AFTER including the other file. Always `start_session()` FIRST

Comment: this question contains too much text and not enough code.

Comment: Added links to code examples now. Couldn't paste in textbox..... And no, session is started before anything else.

Comment: @MattiasOrmestad do you have full error reporting enabled?

Comment: @tereško, I get undefined index (session_email) from the loginCheck method

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, I think you edited in the code am I right? Not sure why I couldn't paste it...

Comment: @MattiasOrmestad I did. It could be a limit applied to new member to stop huge spam messages

Comment: @MattiasOrmestad what do you see , when you add `var_dump($_SESSION);` in `global.php` file (before and after your "user validation" ... that doesn't actually validate but log in instead.

Comment: @tereško just an empty array, and same thing if I do it inside the class

Comment: What do you get, when you call `var_dump(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE);` somewhere in your class?

Comment: Then I get TRUE...

Comment: Then check whether the PHPSESSID cookie is not changing on every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stopped responding to question in comments, I will go with my latest ideas:

Don't use closing `?>` php tags in php-only files. They tend top introduce forgotten whitespaces, what cause the HTML body to sent in unexpected points in of your code.

Those whitespaces could cause the headers to be sent before you start a session, which would mean that the session-cookie gets FUBARed.

The other possible reason would be, that your `global.php` file does not get included, when you think it does, because of `require_once`. I would recommend removing the `_once` part.

---

#### Unrelated part

> <sub>There is much to unpack in this post, so what you get is a "stream of contentiousness" style of code-review.</sub>

What you have there is "include oriented programming". I would strongly recommend for you to learn about autoloaders. Especially the PSR4 autoloader, that comes with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

The use of sha512 hashing algorithm (especially unsalted), is a really bad idea. You should learn to use the (relatively) new [Password API](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

The user email should already be a unique parameter. There is no point in having additional `WHERE` and `LIMIT` conditions, when requesting account details.

When user has logged in, there is no need to store the login credentials in the session. You should instead just store the account ID.

Your classes should not have any business logic in the constructors, because that makes it really hard to test said class.

And you have SQL injection all over the codebase. You should not concatenate the data inside the queries, for the same reason why you don't use `eval()` in your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to looks through the code! And I'm sorry for the delay in my response, I had to clear my head a bit so I went out running... I really appreciate your code review, I'm just a self taught n00b :D I've been thinking I should have a look at composer but haven't really had time to do it yet.

Comment: Hello again! I removed the closing tags (had no idea about that...) and changed from `require_once` to `require`, and I also cleared the cache/cookies of the browser just to be sure. And voila, it worked!

Comment: If you ever come to Stockholm I'll buy you a beer ;)

Comment: The beer in Stockholm costs like wine in Riga :P